# Neo4j: Query performance issue at scale, even with index

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When running this query on a DB instance with thousands of nodes and relationships, I'm running into a long response time:

```
MATCH (user)-[:PROFILE]->(profile)-[:DATES]->(dates) 
WHERE exists(dates.endDate) 
AND datetime(dates.endDate) < datetime('2020-06-20T18:29:04.116Z') 
AND datetime(dates.endDate) > datetime('2019-10-19T18:29:04.116Z') 
RETURN user 
ORDER BY dates.endDate ASC
```

I've added an index to dates:
`CREATE INDEX ON :Dates(endDate)`

But it hasn't improved performance. Is there an issue with the query construction itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index would not be used with your query, for 2 reasons:

1. You are not using the `endDate` directly (you are passing it to a function).
2. You did not specify the `Dates` label in your `MATCH` pattern.

*If all your `endDate` strings have the same exact format as '2020-06-20T18:29:04.116Z'*, then there is actually no need to use the `datetime()` function (which is slowing down the query as well) -- you could just compare the strings directly.

For example, if the above assumption is true, then this query should use your index and be very fast:

```
MATCH (user)-[:PROFILE]->()-[:DATES]->(dates:Dates) 
WHERE '2019-10-19T18:29:04.116Z' < dates.endDate < '2020-06-20T18:29:04.116Z'
RETURN user 
ORDER BY dates.endDate ASC
```

Comment: The above query returns no results if `datetime()` isn't wrapping each endDate string (all formatted as '2020-06-20T18:29:04.116Z' style)

Comment: I also added the `Dates` label to `[:DATES]->(dates:Dates)` but it doesn't increase performance

Comment: It works for me. Does `MATCH (user)-[:PROFILE]->()-[:DATES]->(dates:Dates) RETURN dates LIMIT 1` return anything? And are you sure that the `endDate` format matches exactly?

Comment: `MATCH (user)-[:PROFILE]->()-[:DATES]->(dates:Dates) RETURN dates LIMIT 1` does work. The structure of the returned node is: `{ "endDate": "2019-10-18T04:26:53.689000000Z", "startDate": "2008-08-08T23:16:32.905000000Z" }`

Comment: Actually now I realize the incoming date format is different, will test with fixed formatting

Comment: Modifying the incoming timestamps to match those stored in neo4j works now with removing datetime() functions